# Read specific part of an INI file C#

Tags: c#, .net, io

I have an question about reading an ini file, 
I need to read an specific part of the ini file im using and cannot figure out how to do this,
I can already read and write from and to the ini file but i need to read an specific part.

Here's my INI file:

```
[Settings]

[ACR]
11: Start Removal =90 // ms
12: Removal Time  =20 // commentary
13: Removal Delay =2.1 // commentary

[Cleaning]
21: Dur. Cleaning =90 //commentary
22: Time valve on =30  //commentary
23: Time valve off =15    //commentary

[Calibrate]
31: Content left =100//commentary
32: Calibrate left =--.-//commentary
33: Content right =100//commentary
34: Calibrate right =25.6//commentary

[Conductivity]
41: Factor left =500//commentary
42: Offset left =220//commentary
43: Factor right =500//commentary
44: Offset right =40//commentary
45: Level left =85//commentary
46: Level right =85//commentary

[General]
51: Type of valve =5//commentary
52: Indicator =2//commentary
53: Inverse output =0//commentary
54: Restart time =30//commentary
55: Water time =0//commentary
56: Gate delay =10//commentary

[Pulsation]
61: Pulsation p/m =60//commentary
62: S/r ratio front =55//commentary
63: S/r ratio back =60//commentary
64: Stimulation p/m =200//commentary
65: S/r stim front =30//commentary
66: S/r stim back =30//commentary
67: Stimulation dur =20//commentary
```

I have to read the first 2 characters of the line, so lets so under the section ACR i need to read 10,11 and 12. and with the section cleaning i have to read 21,22,23 and so on.

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Idento.Common.Utilities;
using Milk_Units;

namespace Milk_Units
{
    public class SettingsIniFile
    {
        private const String FileNameCustom = "Data\\Custom.ini";//Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), );
        private const String FileNameDefault = "Data\\Default.ini";//Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), );


        public Settings LoadSettings(bool defaults = false)
        {
            String fileName = defaults ? FileNameDefault : FileNameCustom;
            StringList input = new StringList().FromFile(fileName);

            //Settings settings = null;
            Settings settings = new Settings();

            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                String line = item.Trim();

                if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                    continue;

                int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();

                String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();
                String comment = "";
                index = value.IndexOf("//");
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    comment = value.Substring(index).Trim();
                    value = value.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                }

                // ACR
                if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "10: Start Removal"))
                    settings.AcrStartRemoval = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "11: Removal Time"))
                    settings.AcrRemovalTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "12: Removal Delay"))
                    settings.AcrRemovalDelay = value;
                // CLEANING
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "21: Dur. Cleaning"))
                    settings.CleanDurCleaning = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "22: Time valve on"))
                    settings.CleanTimeValveOn = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "23: Time valve off"))
                    settings.CleanTimeValveOff = value;
                //CALIBRATE
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "31: Content left"))
                    settings.CalibrateContentLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "32: Calibrate left"))
                    settings.CalibrateCalibrateLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "33: Content right"))
                    settings.CalibrateContentRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "34: Calibrate right"))
                    settings.CalibrateCalibrateRight = value;
                //CONDUCTIVITY
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "41: Factor left"))
                    settings.ConductFactorLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "42: Offset left"))
                    settings.ConductOffsetleft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "43: Factor right"))
                    settings.ConductFactorRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "44: Offset right"))
                    settings.ConductOffsetRight = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "45: Level left"))
                    settings.ConductLevelLeft = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "46: Level right"))
                    settings.ConductLevelRight = value;
                //GENERAL
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "51: Type of valve"))
                    settings.GeneralTypeOfValve = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "52: Indicator"))
                    settings.GeneralIndicator = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "53: Inverse output"))
                    settings.GeneralInverseOutput = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "54: Restart time"))
                    settings.GeneralRestartTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "55: Water time"))
                    settings.GeneralWaterTime = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "56: Gate delay"))
                    settings.GeneralGateDelay = value;
                //PULSATION
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "61: Pulsation p/m"))
                    settings.PulsationPulsationPm = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "62: S/r ratio front"))
                    settings.PulsationSrRatioFront = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "63: S/r ratio back"))
                    settings.PulsationSrRatioBack = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "64: Stimulation p/m"))
                    settings.PulsationStimulationPm = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "65: S/r stim front"))
                    settings.PulsationSrStimFront = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "66: S/r stim back"))
                    settings.PulsationSrStimBack = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "67: Stimulation dur"))
                    settings.PulsationStimulationDur = value;



            }
            return settings;
        }
```

Thanks in advance, and i know im using the INI file not properly but this is the easist way.

**Awnser Thank youn Neoistheone for your help**

```
      foreach (var item in input)
                    {
                        String line = item.Trim();

                        if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                            continue;

                        int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                        if (index < 0)
                            continue;

                        String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                        String ID = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':'));
                        String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();
                        //String comment = "";
                        index = value.IndexOf("//");
                        if (index > -1)
                        {
                         ID = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':'));
                            //comment = value.Substring(index).Trim();
                            value = value.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                        }



                        // ACR
                        if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "11: Start Removal"))
                           {
                           settings.AcrStartRemoval11 = value;
                           _settings.AcrId11.ID
                           }
```

Return settings;
                            }

Comment: https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

Comment: I strongly suggest considering moving to app.config-based settings

Comment: @DavidBrabant i have to make it work in my own program or are the sources available

Comment: OMG.. INI files. I haven't seen them since windows 95. That's like... 18 years ago?

Comment: haha i know its outdated but it can be an easy way of saving properties without an database.

Comment: Not any more. SQLite is a very small, very fast, very portable database. You would get so much more flexibility and possibilities out of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
var vals = File.ReadLines("C:\\TEMP\\test.ini")
    .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("[ACR]"))
    .Skip(1)
    .TakeWhile(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .Select(line => new
    {
        Key = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':')),
        Value = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 2)
    });
```

**EXPLANATION**

- `.SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("[ACR]"))` skips until it finds the section it wants.
- `.Skip(1)` skips that line because we really want to read values.
- `.TakeWhile(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))` reads until it finds a blank line.
- `.Select(line => new...` selects the values of each line into an anonymous type.

So, just passing in the right section will get you whatever section you want.

The other benefit of this approach is that it's deferred execution so if you don't have to read the entire file to find the section it won't.

Now, in your case you may need to massage this a little to ensure that it doesn't read the comments at the end of the line for example by changing the last `Substring`. That really depends on the real **domain needs** but that won't be a big modification.

You can of course modify this as well to meet the needs of any other types of queries you need.

Comment: it doesnt work :( because the whole section ACR wont be shown anymore.

Comment: I implemented youre piece of code and tested it but when i started the program it wont read the whole [ACR] section from the ini file so the textboxes are empty.

Comment: @user2721466: does the INI file look like the one in your example? Because that's where I pulled the INI file from for testing. When I run it I get the entire `[ACR]` section in an enumerable of key value pairs.

Comment: Yeah the ini file is the same, Maybe you can use the code of the main form

Comment: @user2721466, you won't be able to just copy and paste my solution into your code. I've given a query that works. If you don't want to return a key value pair, then just change the `Select` to `Select()` and loop through the results to set the values of text boxes.

Comment: i may sound stupid but can you give me an example with a few texboxes because i cannot quite figure out what's the plan.

Comment: @user2721466, think about it like this. The query I gave you returns an object that has two properties on it `Key`, and `Value`. The `Key` is the numeric value (e.g. `10`, `11`, etc.) and the `Value` is the corresponding value. Simply iterate through the results, switch on the `Key`, and set the `Value` to the text box. That's it.

Comment: Ow i think i get it what i but i need to have the 10,11,12 in the textboxes. So to put in in the textboxes i have to so this right.

Comment: else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "10: Dur. Cleaning"))
                    settings.CleaningID10= value;

Comment: @user2721466, the `Key` would only have `10` in it. I've already split the key and value pair. If the text box needs to the `10: ` in it then you could just add another property to the anonymous type ... say `Line` ... and set it `Line = line` and then put the `Line` in the text box.

Comment: Hello, Me again :P, An quick question. When i do the command what do i have to say: else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "here?"))
                  settings.AcrId11 = ID; What do i have to say where the here? is

Comment: @user2721466, please post another question with the modified code and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Neoistheone i've solved it, It was a small problem. The answer ill put under the qestion

Answer (score 2):

> and i know im using the INI file not properly but this is the easist
>   way.

I think that this is NOT the easiest way, try something already implemented:
[GetPrivateProfileSection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120556/838405).

There are 2 useful windows API to read/write ini files:

[GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[WriteProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t453x0d8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

check them out!

Comment: Like i said i only have to read an specific part of the lines, And i can already read and write the file. But i have to know how i can read the first to characters of an line.

Answer (score 1):

```
                   `   namespace TeknoModding
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections;

public class IniFile
{
    private readonly Hashtable _keyPairs = new Hashtable();
    private readonly String _iniFilePath;

    private struct SectionPair
    {
        public String Section;
        public String Key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the INI file at the given path ;and enumerates the values in the IniParser.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="iniPath">Full path to INI file.&lt;/param>
    public IniParser(String iniPath)
    {
        TextReader iniFile = null;
        String strLine = null;
        String currentRoot = null;
        String[] keyPair = null;

        this._iniFilePath = iniPath;

        if(File.Exists(iniPath))
        {
            try
            {
                iniFile = new StreamReader(iniPath);

                strLine = iniFile.ReadLine();

                while (strLine != null)
                {
                    strLine = strLine.Trim();

                   if (strLine != "")
                   {
                       if (strLine.StartsWith("[") && strLine.EndsWith("]"))
                       {
                          currentRoot = strLine.Substring(1, strLine.Length - 2);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          keyPair = strLine.Split(new char[]{ '=' }, 2);

                          SectionPair sectionPair;
                          String value = null;

                          if (currentRoot == null)
                              currentRoot = "ROOT";

                          sectionPair.Section = currentRoot;
                          sectionPair.Key = keyPair[0];

                          if (keyPair.Length > 1)
                              value = keyPair[1];

                          this._keyPairs.Add(sectionPair, value);
                       }
                   }

                   strLine = iniFile.ReadLine();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (iniFile != null)
                   iniFile.Close();
            }
        }
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to locate " + iniPath);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the ;value for the given section, key pair.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionName">Section name.</param>
    /// <param name="settingName">Key name.</param>
    public string GetSetting(string sectionName, string settingName)
    {
        try
        {
        SectionPair sectionPair;
        sectionPair.Section = sectionName;
        sectionPair.Key = settingName;

        return (String)this._keyPairs[sectionPair];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerates alllines for given section.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionName">Section to enum.</param>;
    public string[] EnumSection(string sectionName)
    {
        ArrayList tmpArray = new ArrayList();

        foreach (SectionPair pair in this._keyPairs.Keys)
        {
            if (pair.Section == sectionName)
                tmpArray.Add(pair.Key);
        }

        return (String[])tmpArray.ToArray(typeof(String));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds or replaces a setting to the tableto be saved.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionName">Section to add under.<;/param>
    /// <param name="settingName">Key name to add.</param>
    /// <param name="settingValue">Value of key.</param>
    public void AddSetting(string sectionName, string settingName, string settingValue)
    {
        SectionPair sectionPair;
        sectionPair.Section = sectionName;
        sectionPair.Key = settingName;

        if(this._keyPairs.ContainsKey(sectionPair))
            this._keyPairs.Remove(sectionPair);

        this._keyPairs.Add(sectionPair, settingValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds or replaces a setting to the tableto be saved with a nullvalue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionName">Section to add under.<;/param>
    /// <param name="settingName">Key name to add.</param>
    public void AddSetting(string sectionName, string settingName)
    {
        AddSetting(sectionName, settingName, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove a setting.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionName">Section to add under.<;/param>
    /// <param name="settingName">Key name to add.</param>
    public void DeleteSetting(string sectionName, string settingName)
    {
        SectionPair sectionPair;
        sectionPair.Section = sectionName;
        sectionPair.Key = settingName;

        if(this._keyPairs.ContainsKey(sectionPair))
            this._keyPairs.Remove(sectionPair);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save settingsto new file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newFilePath">New file path.</param>
    public void SaveSettings(string newFilePath)
    {
        ArrayList sections = new ArrayList();
        string tmpValue = "";
        string strToSave = "";

        foreach (SectionPair sectionPair in this._keyPairs.Keys)
        {
            if (!sections.Contains(sectionPair.Section))
                sections.Add(sectionPair.Section);
        }

        foreach (string section in sections)
        {
            strToSave += ("[" +section + "]\r\n");

            foreach (SectionPair sectionPair in this._keyPairs.Keys)
            {
                if (sectionPair.Section == section)
                {
                   tmpValue = (String)this._keyPairs[sectionPair];

                   if (tmpValue != null)
                       tmpValue = "=" + tmpValue;

                   strToSave += (sectionPair.Key + tmpValue + "\r\n");
                }
            }

            strToSave += "\r\n";
        }

        try
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(newFilePath);
            tw.Write(strToSave);
            tw.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save settingsback to ini file.
    /// </summary>
    public void SaveSettings()
    {
        SaveSettings(this._iniFilePath);
    }`
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third=party class that reads INI files:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C

Comment: 1966? Are ini files that old? :)

Comment: @ya23 Well, no... The article is actually from 2002, the 1966 number in the link has nothing to do with the year...

Comment: I know, hence ":)" in my comment. Just a (poor) joke attempt.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, there are much better ways to save your setting than a pseudo-INI file, but if you must, you can use regex to parse your strings:

```
void Main()
{

    string line1 = "[ACR]";
    string line2 = "53: Inverse output =0.3//commentary";

    var a = Regex.Match(line1,@"^\[(.*)\]").Groups;
    var b = Regex.Match(line2,@"^(\d\d):\s*(.*)\s*=(.*)//(.*)").Groups;

    string sectionName = a[1].Value;

    string number = b[1].Value;
    string setting = b[2].Value;
    string value = b[3].Value;
    string comment = b[4].Value;

}
```