# Create INI file for use in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ini

just wanted some help in creating a INI file in windows using notepad to declare paths used for files/directories for a C#.NET application in Visual Studio.

Currently the program uses hard-coded paths in the application to location of files (on the network drives) used for input and output.  What I want to do is use this INI file to declare these locations for files on my local machine so I can test out the program and then read it by the C#.NET program without modifying the production source code.

How do I go about doing this and how is it used once file is created?

Thanks

Comment: Over the last 20 years a number of better storage mechanisms than INI files have  been developed such as XML, JSON,  binary serialization and even `Settings`

Comment: I know this feels like a broad swath of work; but if you break it down:  You need a place to store your INI file.  Look up how to do file creation/reading in C#.  You then need to parse this INI File; meaning to learn the INI File format, or see if there's a C# parser for INI.  Once you've done that, you need to load those INI settings into an object to use during the life of your application; again, that's an individual google search.  (In .NET Core the Configuration Class can do this easily https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is possible to achieve but we're here to help you, not to do it for you. Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Check Settings. It is much easier than reading writing ini files. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18700183/578411

Comment: The INI file format has massive amounts of appcompat associated with them.  Reading a single setting from such a file takes 50 milliseconds on a spindle drive.  That makes it unsuitable for use today.  Use Project > Properties > Settings, press F1 to learn more.

Comment: The only redeeming feature of ini format is that it is easily user-editable. If you don't absolutely need a format that is dead simple for end users to open in notepad and manually change settings in, I advise using the default xml settings system, as indicated by some other people here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could use App.config: 
Try this:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="parametro_de_lo_que_sea" value="valor_que_sea" />
  </appSettings>
```

In your application you could use AppSettings.Get to get value:

```
string obtain_value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["parametro_de_lo_que_sea"];
```

Good luck !!

Comment: You would unlikely want to do such a thing when there is Settings.