# Why does GetPrivateProfileSection retrieve each character as a two byte value, padding them with a NULL character?

Tags: vb.net, ini, kernel32, nul

Given this piece of code:

```
Private Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileSection Lib "kernel32" _
        (ByVal lpAppName As String, _
         ByVal lpszReturnBuffer As Byte(), _
         ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer

Public Class IniClassReader
    Public Function readWholeSection(iniFile as String, section as String) as String()
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(SECTIONLENGTH) {}
        GetPrivateProfileSection(section, buffer, SECTIONLENGTH, iniFile)
        Dim sectionContent As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)
        ' Skipped code embedded in the function below, not the point of the question
        return processSectionContent(sectionContent)
    End Function
End Class
```

I figured out that `buffer` contains a sequence of bytes interspersed with `NULL` characters (`\0`). Hence, `sectionContent` value is seen by the spying variable feature as `'e n t r i e 1 = v a l u e 1  e n t r i e 2 = v a l u e 2'`. Each pair key/value is as expected followed by two `NULL` characters instead of one.

I don't see why each character is stored as a two byte value. **Replacing `Default` by `UTF8` gives the same result.** I tried with a INI file encoded in UTF8 and Windows-1252 (so called "ANSI" by Microsoft).

I know how to get ride of those extra bytes:

```
Dim sectionContent As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer)
sectionContent = sectionContent.Replace(Chr(0) & Chr(0), vbNewLine).Replace(Chr(0), "")
```

But I want to understand what's going on here to apply the best solution instead of some sloppy hack working only on some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes are UTF-16 encoded text.  It looks like null character padding because all of your text consists of characters whose encodings fit in the low byte.

The Windows API exposes both an "A" and a "W" version of the function, with the "A" version working in narrow strings and the "W" version working in wide strings.  The default for the Windows NT family tree (thus all Windows since XP) is wide as UCS-2/UTF-16 is the "native" Windows character encoding.

Comment: It makes sense now. I didn't figured it out in first place since another kernel32  function, `GetPrivateProfileString()`, is callable with a `StringBuilder` instead of a `Byte()` array as the buffer. This is not `GetPrivateProfileSection()` due to the NULL character as separator. The difference between `GetPrivateProfileSection()` and `GetPrivateProfileSectionA()` is barely noticable in Microsoft's [Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/). Thanks to your answer, I might be able to write a clean way to deal with it.

Comment: That said, I wonder why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120556/4375327) was marked as accepted.

Comment: @Amessihel It doesn't surprise me that `StringBuilder` would work instead of `Byte()`.  As with `lpAppName`, the native .NET string format is UTF-16, and the interop features are designed to do string translations as necessary when they understand the types involved on each side (you lose that with `Byte()`).

Comment: Re the accepted answer you linked, I have no idea why they didn't see any issues with it.

Comment: (There is a typo in my first comment: it should be read: "this is not **the case of** `GetPrivateProfileSection()` due to the NULL character as separator.")

Comment: yes, but string retrieval from StringBuilder fails due to the NULL separator. I'm looking now for a way to solve this.

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, of course.  It won't work in this case because you're dealing with a null-char-delimited string array rather than a null-terminated string, which is what the interop expects a string argument to be.  So you're looking for 00 00 as the delimiters, and 00 00 00 00 as the terminal.  You probably need to work with ranges of the byte array, I'm not sure if .NET strings can deal with embedded null chars the way COM strings can.  If they can, then I guess you could dump everything into a string and work from there.

Comment: I get it. Thanks @Craig for your help, wish I could upvote more than once.